# How to update Baldur's Gate 3 to the latest patch

Tags: steam, macos, baldurs-gate-3

I have Baldur's Gate 3 installed on Steam on MacOs. A couple of days ago Patch #6 was released, but my version is not up-to-date.

I tried changing all the possible combinations of options for `Automatic Updates` and `Background Download` in the settings in `Library\Baldur's Gate 3\Manage/Properties\Updates`, but when I launch the game no update/download is triggered.

(Before you ask: I have plenty of space on my hard drive)

**Is there a way to force an update on Baldur's Gate 3?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [not out yet on Mac](https://baldursgate3.game/news/patch-6-now-live_108)

> We know Mac players will be keen to get hands-on with the latest fixes and improvements, but we’ll have to ask that you sit tight for a little longer while we continue to work on bringing future updates to Mac alongside PC versions.